# Sending mass email with a loop and exclusions?

Tags: excel, vba, email

I am trying to send out emails using a Do...Until Loop. I am not very experienced in VBA at all and I'm just trying to figure out how to send emails from excel and have the code stop at a blank space or a 0 (as I am using references from other workbooks to keep it updated).

I have tried changing it to a For...Next statement as well but that did not work.

```
Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, subject_line As String, mail_body 
    As String)

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

olMail.To = what_address
olMail.Subject = subject_line
olMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
olMail.HTMLBody = mail_body
olMail.Send


End Sub

Sub SendMassEmail()

row_number = 1

Do
DoEvents
  row_number = row_number + 1
  Dim mail_body_message As String
  Dim full_name As String
  Dim policy_number As String
  Dim address As String
  Dim city As String
  Dim day As String
  Dim web_address As String

  mail_body_message = Sheet5.Range("I2")
  full_name = Sheet5.Range("B" & row_number) & " " & Sheet5.Range("C" & 
    row_number)
  policy_number = Sheet5.Range("F" & row_number)
  address = Sheet5.Range("D" & row_number)
  city = Sheet5.Range("E" & row_number)
  day = Sheet5.Range("G" & row_number)
  web_address = Sheet5.Range("H1")
  mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_name_here", 
    full_name)
  mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "policy_number_replace", 
    policy_number)
  mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "day_replace", day)
  mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "address_replace", 
    address)
  mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "city_replace", city)
  mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "web_replace", 
    web_address)
  Call SendEmail(Sheet5.Range("A" & row_number), "Insurance update", 
    mail_body_message)
Loop Until row_number = 2

MsgBox "Complete!"

End Sub
```

Ideally this would read through the rows and send out emails related to my email body. It would exclude the 0s from my reference formulas and blank spaces where there is no data. I keep getting a run-time error when I do not manually set the row_number for the loop. It emails regardless but it is stopping an auto_open sub from running

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error message you are receiving, and which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: Run-time error'-2147477259(80004005)': We need to know who to send this to. Make sure you enter at least one name.   The macro works fine to actually send emails as long as I have the right cell for the code section: Loop Until row_number =s part. I'm just trying to add some line that tells it to stop sending if it doesn't have a valid email or text message format. If it's blank or 0 basically. Also how does VBA read the 0s from my reference formulas? Is it reading it as an actual 0 or just a placeholder? I'm extremely new to this.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim row_number As Integer
```

is missing

Comment: If I add that it gives me the compile error: duplicate declaration in current scope